# How to get data for channel url without id or username?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I just stumbled upon YouTube url https://www.youtube.com/u2. It leads to a channel page. When I click on a video of the channel and then on the video's channel link, I get back to the same page, but with the url https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4gPNusMDwx2Xm-YI35AkCA.

But how can I go from https://www.youtube.com/u2 to https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4gPNusMDwx2Xm-YI35AkCA using the YouTube Data API? The API reference for channel does not document a way to do this. I can do a search for u2 with type channel, and that will give me the channel id, but it will also give me other channel ids. And for a channel, there seems to be no data that lists https://www.youtube.com/u2 as an alternative url.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no way to get the channel ID via the API (which I don't know for sure), what should work is downloading the site (etc. using curl or your programming languages's prefered way of making HTTP requests) and parsing it. The link to the actual channel page is contained a couple of times in the HTML source (in the `<head>`), as you can see from this excerpt:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4gPNusMDwx2Xm-YI35AkCA">

<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4gPNusMDwx2Xm-YI35AkCA">
<meta property="og:title" content="U2">
<meta property="og:description" content="Rock band from Dublin, Ireland. Adam Clayton on Bass. The Edge on Guitar. Larry Mullen Jr on Drums. Bono on Vocals. http://www.u2.com">
```

Even if you don't want to fully parse the site and extract the header information, a regex search with `<link rel="canonical" href="https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/channel\/(.+)">` might do the trick, but be advised this is not guaranteed to work 100%.

Comment: Thank you. This works well, and with jsoup (https://jsoup.org/) it's just a few lines of code. So, my problem is solved for now, and I have upvoted your answer, but I am reluctant to mark it as the correct answer, since this is an inofficial solution that may get broken in the future without notice.

Comment: I wish I could find another way than using a regex, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I did not find it when I posted the question or whether it is new, but now the YouTube data API has `snippet.customUrl` for channels, which is `"u2"` in the given example. So you can do this:

```kotlin
// Kotlin

fun getChannelById(id: String): Channel? =
    youTube.channels().list("id, snippet")
        .setKey(apiKey)
        .setId(id)
        .execute()
        .items
        ?.single()

private fun getChannelByCustomUrl(customUrl: String): Channel? =
    youTube.search().list("id, snippet")
        .setKey(apiKey)
        .setType("channel")
        .setQ(customUrl)
        // .setMaxResults(5) // The default value 5 should suffice.
        .execute()
        .items
        ?.asSequence()
        ?.mapNotNull {
            // Can be null when channel has been deleted just after search().
            this.getChannelById(it.snippet.channelId)
        }
        ?.firstOrNull { it.snippet.customUrl == customUrl }
```